# Sorting named ranges into order based on range name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Apr-17</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Totals</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>May-17</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Totals</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Jun-17</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td><td>Heading</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row label</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Totals</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I have been trying to write a VBA macro to sort named ranges into reverse chronological order. I have a number of sheets where tables start from cell A1 and end a few rows down, where another table will start with the same characteristics. I will need to move the entire rows where the table is located.

Currently I have written code to run down the sheet, finding start and end rows using the `.End(xlDown)` function and then add names to the ranges based on the top left-most cell denoted by the date in dd/mm/yyyy format (converted into serial for sorting later)

Here is the code I have currently written:

```
Sub Rearrange()

Dim block As Range
Dim firstCell As Range

Set firstCell = Range("A1")

Do ' run through the entire sheet
Set block = Range(firstCell, firstCell.End(xlDown).EntireRow) 'define the block as the first cell to the last column in the row

block.Name = CDbl(firstCell) 'set the range name as the firstCell value (date in serial format)

Set firstCell = firstCell.End(xlDown).End(xlDown) 'move to the next table by using xlDown twice

Loop Until firstCell.Row > 100000 ' loop until the firstCell row reaches the bottom of the sheet


'move named ranges based on descending named range order with an empty row separator

For Each ActiveSheet.Name In ActiveSheet ' this is where it gets confusing

'cut and insert the highest value named range in cell A1
'insert blank row below named range

'Cut and insert the next highest value named range between cell under blank row from table above.
'insert blank row below named range.

'rinse and repeat for the entire sheet.

End Sub
```

I will be eternally grateful for any help with this!

EDIT: sample table structure

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet?

Comment: What is not working? Error messages?

Comment: Where I get confused on how to write the logic is where I've written 'this is where it gets confusing'. The code comments denote the logic about how to achieve the task but my noodle is unable to guide my fingers to write logical VBA code!

Comment: I have added HTML code to illustrate a sample of the table layout @Zac. Hope this helps!